# Need to go Javascript Method before hit the MVC controller method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC project. I need to do client side validation on run time. When click the form submit button I need to hit JavaScript Method first and then it is return true move to Controller method.

Just Assume following code type:

JavaScript OnClick Method:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSave').on('click', function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Service/Utility/ThresholdValidation',
            type: $("#addNewOrderForm").attr('method'),
            data: $("#addNewOrderForm").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
               if (data != "") {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   alert(data);
                   return false;
               }
               else {
                   return true;
               }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[BaseAuthenticationFilter(UserTypeEnum.Admin, PermissionEnum.CanSendRemittance)]
public ActionResult Create(Invoice model)
{
   // Method Goes here
}
```

Here I cant popup validation alert message. When I click the button it will hit the Controller method. I need to go first javascript method and then if true go to controller method

Please help this.

Comment: Hook to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the `click` of `#btnSave`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code, you have to return false in click handler directly instead of ajax response event. because ajax is asynchronous it will execute the ajax and call out from event handler immediately before getting the response of ajax.

So check if data not exists then submit the form otherwise show validation message

```
$('#btnSave').on('click', function (event) {
   $.ajax({
       url: '/Service/Utility/ThresholdValidation',
       type: $("#addNewOrderForm").attr('method'),
       data: $("#addNewOrderForm").serialize(),
       success: function (data) {
           if (data != "") {
               alert(data);
           }
           else {
               $("form").submit();
           }
       }
   });

   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```